# Headless JS is not working in React Native

Tags: react-native

Hello I am trying to do the background action in react native. I already tested a lot of libreries and no one is not working.
Now I am trying to do background task using the Headless JS.

I am using React-Native-CLI

```js
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, Button} from 'react-native';
import { View } from 'react-native';


const bgTask = () => {
  console.log('Working in background!')
}

const regBG = () => {
  console.log('Pressed')
  AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('Task', () => bgTask());
}

function App(){
  
  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Press" onPress={() => regBG()} />
    </View>
  );
}


export default App;
```

After the push on 'Press' button console showing the log message 'Pressed' and it's all.

[console img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkSQc.png)

Handless JS, React Native Background Task, React Native Background Action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are just registering the event, not calling it. You need some additional setup on the native side, which is where you will define the `task` that will be called (which you registered as `Task`, as well as the `timeout` before it to be called. [(Here are the docs)](https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android#the-platform-api).

Also, I would try exporting the method you want to call from another module, instead of calling a function from the same component you're registering the action in. [(Check this example from the documentation)](https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android#the-js-api).

Third, I'm not sure you will see that event log in the terminal, depending on how long the app's been in `foreground`. In case you don't see that log after the additional setup mentioned in the documentation, try an `API call` to a local server instead of a `console.log`, so you can check from the `server` log wether it's been called or not.

Last but not least, remember that this method is for `Android only`, and there are other ways for doing this on `iOS`, so make sure you're testing from an Android device/simulator.